# How to perform a function with a checked radio button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, radio-button, checked

I want to do some action with a checked radio button in jQuery however am not quite sure how to do this.

I have a group of radio buttons and I get the checked radio button using this code:

```
var solid_checked = ($('#solidcolor input[name=asw_options[box_background_color]]:checked').val());
```

How can I now say add a css class to that checked radio button. I want to add a CSS class to only the checked radio button and not the others.

Was trying to do something like this:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

EDIT

What I am doing is using images as radio buttons using CSS and jQuery.
You click on an image to select it and you end up with an orange border around it.
Then you save the settings.

When the page reloads I want the checked radio button (image) to remain with the orange border but I can't get it to work.

This is the jQuery which I use to initially highlight the radio button (image)

```
$('#solidcolor input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#solidcolor label').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

How can I now add the:

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

class to the script so that it highlights the checked radio button?

Want to try to achieve something like this:

```
if($("input[name='asw_options[box_background_color]']").is(':checked')) {
$(this).css("border", "solid 3px orange");
}
```

or

```
if($("input[name='asw_options[box_background_color]']").is(':checked')) {
$(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

but none of these work.

Comment: So what is not working? Also post your html code and a demo is even better.

Comment: If you want to 'save' the setting so that the page remembers it when it reloads, then you need to do just that: save it. Post the setting to your server and save it (probably using ajax), and then in your load page method, load the setting and attach it to the target element

Comment: I can save the setting no problem. When the page reloads I can see the radio button which is checked (if I comment out the first jQuery line of code). I just want to add a css class to that certain checked radio button.

Answer (score 3):

To add a class to the checked element of a radio group, select only the checked element using `:checked` and then add the class:

```
$('input[name=radiogroup]:checked').addClass('classname');
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: I read the jQuery site however the site gives an example on the "Click" event. I want to achieve the jQuery on the page load.

Comment: @Jason to run code (or bind events) on page load, put it inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I have the jQuery inside a wrapper. I just left the wrapper out to shorten the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `change` event:

```
$('#solidcolor input[name^="asw_options"]').change(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
```